# Shifting matrix from an approximated matrix

Tags: matrices

If I have a function of $z(k_1,k_2)$, when I say $z(k_1,k_2)$ also can be approximated as $z(k_1,k_2) \approx ak_1+bk_2 $ due to some shifting coefficients  $a$ and $b$, what does it exactly mean? Does that resulting in the moved matrix as $z(k_1,k_2)_{shifted}=z(k_1,k_2)-(ak_1+bk_2)$? But I can't perform the subtract operation since the dimensions are not equal.

Any explanation or advice on this matter? Thank you.